# What is the difference between npm start and serve s build?

Tags: reactjs, build, startup

I know two way to deploy server is `npm start` and `serve s build`

So what different between `npm start` and `serve s build` to start server in react js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are all custom script, you can find the definition in `package.json` file. Normally `start` is for starting the development build, `build` is for making the production build.

Ex.

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "lint": "eslint ./src",
    "lint:fix": "eslint ./src --fix",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "test:coverage": "react-scripts test --coverage --watchAll=false",
    "build": "rollup -c",
```